# Finding records that match a datetime in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a database that stores an entry and a date (apart from created_at and modified_at). I also have a loop that spits out a date for the previous 10 days. The loop looks like this:

```
<ol>
    <% Date.today.downto(Date.today - 9.days) do |date| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to date.strftime("%A, %B %e"), new_entry_path + date.strftime("/%Y/%m/%d") %>
        </li>
    <% end  %>
</ol>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish, and failing miserably at, is to only show the link above if the entry for that date doesn't exist in the database. If it does exist, I'd show `Entry.title`. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<%= link_to date.strftime("%A, %B %e"), new_entry_path + date.strftime("/%Y/%m/%d") unless Entry.find_by_date(date) %>
```

I've experimented with all sorts of .finds and .wheres, but nothing is working. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, use a console and test whether `Entry.find_by_date(Date.today)` and `Entry.find_by_date(Date.today - x)` finds a record about which you know that is should be found.

In your database, the date is stored as a date, or as a date and time? '2011-02-12' is not equal to '2011-02-12 11:16:05'. Maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Arsen7. Please check the type of *date* column. I too suspect its declared as *datetime* and not *date*.